# how to download from http url (e.g. with webbrowser) to a specific path location?

Tags: python, download, python-webbrowser

I want to give a specific path to save file downloaded from http url

the code below dumps the file to my Downloads directory.

import webbrowser

url = 'https://some_api_path&params=SOME_PARAMS&download=true'

webbrowser.open(url)

I need to control destiny path/filename of downloaded file (via chrome browser) in order to filter downloaded files based on params passed to api.

Comment: while webbrowser.open() downloads the file SUCCESSFULLY, using urllib.request.urlopen(url) or urllib.request.urlretrieve(url) with the same path (!) gives me this error: URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch

Comment: import wget
wget.download(url) produces same error SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use module Requests

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo@2x.png'
myfile = requests.get(url)
open('./pythonlogo.png', 'wb').write(myfile.content)
```

Saved File "pythonlogo.png" to the current folder!

Comment: works great. THANKS. should change 'w' to 'wb', otherwise gets an error: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes